# If statement is always false in c++

Tags: c++

I'm working my way thought Bjarne Stroustrup Programming Principles  and Practice (4.64 Drill #6) and for some reason I can't get "if" to be true.

- I've initialized my variables to -1000.
- I can't initialize to null.
- I've tried just declaring them
- I've tried  changing the order of my variables.

The problems I've found on stack overflow my code is much different than theirs. 
I've currently added a vector which I wasn't using prior.

```
double val1 = 0;  // initialized

double smaller; // initialized
double larger = 0;  // initialized


vector<double> compare; // empty vector of doubles


int main ()
{
    cout << "Please input a value, us | to stop\n"; // put into

    while (cin >> val1)   // cin "get from"
    {
        compare.push_back(val1);

        if (val1 < smaller)
        {
            smaller = val1; // assignment giving a variable a new value
            cout << val1 << " is the smallest so far \n" ;
            compare.push_back(smaller);
        }
        else if (val1 > larger)
        {
            larger = val1;   // assignment giving a variable a new value
            cout << val1 << " is the largest so far \n";
            compare.push_back(larger);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << val1 << " error\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get  smaller "is the smallest so far to print.

I'm teaching myself so any input would be greatly appreciated if anything in my code isn't correct or the best practices please let me know.

Thank You in Advance,

Comment: Don't create arbitrary global variables like you have here. Move those definitions closer to where they're actually used. This would help you spot mistakes like not initializing something despite saying it's "// initialized".

Comment: @KenWhite _smaller_ is global so initialized to 0

Comment: what is your problem ? if you enter -1 you have "-1 is the smallest so far" then if you enter 2 you have "2 is the largest so far" then if you enter -3 you have "-3 is the smallest so far " then if you enter 1 you have "1 error". Out of the fact to print error is strange because possible all is correct

Comment: `smaller` is initialised to `0.0`; If you enter anything other than negative numbers your `smaller` is actually going to be bigger.

Comment: @Cubic no if we enter only positive values _smaller_ stay at 0 because `(val1 < smaller)` is never true

Comment: What do you want to happen when the first number is entered? Should it be reported as both the largest and the smallest? Or neither? Or what?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but each time that `smaller` or `larger` is changed, `val1` gets pushed onto `compare` for a second time. That may be what's intended, but it seems a bit odd.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, this is why I propose to replace the _vector_ by a _set_ in my answer

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is a good question, for me it seems logical the first entered number is reported as both the largest and the smallest, this is why I suppose that in my answer and indicate changes for

Comment: Thank you everyone for the positive feedback!

Comment: Sorry guys the issue is I had my else state to output error.  I was confusing myself, I just changed it to neither the smallest nor the largest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value enter must be **both** the *larger* and the *smaller* whatever that value, for that you need to initialize *smaller* with `INFINITY` (all valid values are smaller) and *larger* with `-INFINITY` (all valid values are larger) and to remove the *else* to have the two clauses effective for the first value, the third clause has no sense and must be removed.

Is it also useless to use global variables, I encourage you to not use global variables the more you can.

Because the same value can be enter several time perhaps you want a *set* rather than a *vector* to not save several times the same value ? However you do not use *compare* after ...

You write the message *Please input...* only one time, in that case it is more consistent to say *Please input value***s**... or replace

> ```
> cout << "Please input a value, us | to stop\n"; // put into
>
> while (cin >> val1)   // cin "get from"
> {
> ```

by

```
while (cout << "Please input a value, invalid value or EOF to stop" << endl,
       cin >> val)   // cin "get from"
```

Your code can be changed to be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  double val;
  double smaller = INFINITY; // initialized
  double larger = -INFINITY;  // initialized
  vector<double> compare; // empty vector of doubles

  cout << "Please input values, give an invalid value or EOF to stop" << endl; // put into

  while (cin >> val)   // cin "get from"
  {
    compare.push_back(val);

    if (val < smaller)
    {
      smaller = val; // assignment giving a variable a new value
      cout << val << " is the smallest so far" << endl;
      compare.push_back(smaller);
    }

    if (val > larger)
    {
      larger = val;   // assignment giving a variable a new value
      cout << val << " is the largest so far" << endl;
      compare.push_back(larger);
    }
  }

  // do something with compare ?

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Please input values, give an invalid value or EOF to stop
1234
1234 is the smallest so far 
1234 is the largest so far 
1
1 is the smallest so far 
222
222222
222222 is the largest so far 
-123
-123 is the smallest so far 
23
45
aze
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: In C++, the header is cmath, not math.h.

Comment: @antred I know `math.h` because also ok for C, but whatever the fact _cmath_ includes _math.h_ you are right and I edit my answer, thank you for the advice

Comment: Thank you for the help, the else statement was originally to say neither the smallest or the largest.  I can figure that out!  Thank you to everyone for all the help I should have came here 3 days ago lol.

Comment: @glucaio if I understand well some of your edits was rejected, I cannot be alone to decide to reject, so there was a consensus to reject, are you sure the OPs rejecting was all wrong ? When an edit is rejected you have the reason no ? Do you have some edits waiting for confirmation I can look to may be explain you if there is a problem ? Be sure I also accept lot of edits, I come on S.O. to help, not to disturb or to get 'pleasure' to reject and DV ...

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your variables to `INFINITY`.

```
double smaller =  INFINITY;
double larger  = -INFINITY;
```

The first value will be smaller/larger than any of those, so you don't limit their value range.

edit: As somebody in the comments pointed out, you would also have to remove the `else` between the smaller/larger parts, as for that first round, both would apply. As for the third case, not sure what that is meant to do.

Comment: Thank you, I never knew you could initialize to INFINITY!

Comment: Just for reference #include <math.h> is needed for INFINITY, and #include <limits.h> is needed for LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN.